# iPhone-SDK: UITextView doesn't show the newline key

Tags: iphone, newline, uitextview

I could get the keyboard to work but on a UITextView but some how the new line key doesn't show up.

please help me

thanks

Comment: You mean there is no return key on the keyboard, or do you mean that the newline character never get entered into your text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the (UIKeyboardType)keyboardType and (UIReturnKeyTYpe) returnKeyType 
The options are documented here

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits

if you are building in code.

If you are using IB then just go to the first inspector panel and set the TextInputTraits

Comment: That's right, but the important caveat that might trip you up is, depending on how you set things up, you'll probably need to handle sending the newline character to the UITextView yourself.